Which hyperparameters should I adjust to improve accuracy?
I would like to know how to increase the accuracy score and lower the loss in a multilabel classification problem.
If you look at the sklearn reference, there is a mention of multilabel in Multiclass and multioutput algorithms and I am testing it now.
(https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html)
The sample data had 10 features using make_multilabel_classification in sklearn.datasets, and a dataset was created by modifying n_classes.
When there are two classes in multilabel, it seems that the accuracy and loss are somewhat satisfactory.
from numpy import mean
from numpy import std
from sklearn.datasets import make_multilabel_classification
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, hamming_loss

# define dataset
X, y = make_multilabel_classification(n_samples=10000, n_features=10, n_classes=2, random_state=1)

# summarize dataset shape
print(X.shape, y.shape)
# summarize first few examples
for i in range(10):
 print(X[i], y[i])

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.2, random_state=101)

from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
scaler = StandardScaler()
scaler.fit(X_train)
print(scaler.mean_)
print(scaler.var_)

x_train_std = scaler.transform(X_train)
x_test_std = scaler.transform(X_test)

knn = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=3)
knn.fit(x_train_std, y_train)

pred = knn.predict(x_test_std)

print(accuracy_score(y_test, pred))
print(hamming_loss(y_test, pred))

accuracy_score: 0.8345, hamming_loss: 0.08875
However, as the number of classes exceeds 3, the accuracy score gradually decreases and the loss increases.
# define dataset
X, y = make_multilabel_classification(n_samples=10000, n_features=10, n_classes=3, random_state=1)

n_classes= 3 --> accuracy_score: 0.772, hamming_loss: 0.116
n_classes= 4 --> accuracy_score: 0.4875, hamming_loss: 0.194125
This is also similary when using the RandomForestClassifier algorithm and MLPClassifier algorithm, as shown in Reference, or when using ClassifierChain(estimator=SVC) to use an algorithm that does not support Multilabel classification.
Which hyperparameters should I adjust to improve accuracy?

When dealing with data containing anonymous features and records, employing grid search to determine optimal parameters through hyperparameter tuning is advisable. Sklearn offers various hyperparameter tuning systems, among which GridSearchCV stands out for its efficacy. It often yields superior results in a shorter timeframe compared to randomized search. However, the choice between these methods ultimately depends on the specific dataset being utilized.
To utilize grid search, one should define potential parameters in a dictionary format and supply them along with the model to GridSearchCV
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

# define hypertuning parameters
parameters = {'n_neighbors':[3, 5, 10, 15]}

knn = KNeighborsClassifier()
clf = GridSearchCV(knn, parameters)

# Fit the GridSearchCV object to the data
clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Get the best parameters
best_params = clf.best_params_

print("Best parameters found:", best_params)

Feel free to add more tuning parameters for the model. For further information about the GridSearchCV please refer the page.
